# Cant cout item in container with std::any

Tags: c++, unordered-map, ostream, stdany

This script

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <any>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unordered_map<int, any> test;
    test[5] = "Hey!";
    cout << test[5];
    return 0;
}
```

Why does it not work?

```
candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__ndk1::unordered_map<int, std::__ndk1::any, std::__ndk1::hash<int>, std::__ndk1::equal_to<int>, std::__ndk1::allocator<std::__ndk1::pair<const int, std::__ndk1::any> > >::mapped_type' (aka 'std::__ndk1::any') to 'const void *' for 1st argument; take the address of the argument with &
    basic_ostream& operator<<(const void* __p);
```

Sorry if this sounds a little stupid

Comment: You need to `std::any_cast` it to a specific type

Comment: You can't do anything with `std::any` directly, you need to use `std::any_cast` to extract the contained value

Comment: @AlanBirtles not strictly true. You can copy or move the `any`, or replace the value it contains

Comment: You should get used to reading the documentation on a regular basis. [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

Comment: `std::any` is cool, but it is needed quite rarely. Mixing it with `std::unordered_map` is strange. That is why I would recommend you to explain why you think your code needs  `std::unordered_map<int, std::any>`, I'm pretty sure there is better solution for your task your code should solve.

Comment: A heterogeneous array of user inputs, using unordered_map<int so the user can skip values (I'm sure there is a better method of doing that that I dont know)

Comment: [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) might be more appropriate if allowed types are limited

Comment: Ok, so any_cast works, but what if I don't even know what the type that the any is covering is? Making a catch() for every type is inefficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `any_cast` to `test[5]`. The main reason for this cast, is to tell the compiler which overloaded function of `<<` is to be called for `test[5]`, `<<` doesn't have any function defined for `std::any`. Hence, we told the compiler to call `const char *` or `std::string` overload function of `<<`.

Always, make sure that `sizeof` of allocation of `test[n]` must match the `sizeof` type-cast.
For an example:

`sizeof(std::string) = 32 bytes`

`sizeof(const char *) = 8 bytes`

That's why we first need to allocate `test[5]` using `std::string("Hey!");`, instead of just `"Hey!"`.

But, `sizeof(int *)` is equal to `sizeof(char *)`, if you did this, it can cause 3 problems:

1. segfault
2. undefined behavior
3. *Exception: `std::bad_any_cast`*

##### Fix

```cpp
std::cout << std::any_cast<const char *>(test[5]);
```

or `std::string`

```cpp
test[5] = std::string("Hey!");
std::cout << std::any_cast<std::string>(test[5]);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because there is no defined overload for the `<<` operator for a `std::ostream` and `std::any`.

`<<` is defined for string literals, `std::string`s, numbers, and a few other specific objects. `std::any` is none of those.

Just because it happens to actually contain a string doesn't make it into a `std::string` or anything else. Just because you open the door to your car, go inside and sit down, or put your dog into the car, or a bunch of groceries, doesn't turn your car into a human, or dog, or a bunch of vegetables. It's still a car, just with something inside it.

So there is no `<<` operator defined for this. That's what your C++ compiler is telling you: it needs the `<<` operator defined for `std::ostream` and `std::any` and there isn't one.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the error you can use `std::any_cast` which gives type-safe access to the contained object, as shown below:

```
std::cout <<  std::any_cast<const char*>(test[5]);
```

Or

```
test[5] = std::string("Hey!");    
std::cout <<  std::any_cast<std::string>(test[5]);
```